# Getting ActionBarOverylayLayout in layout but missing all components

Tags: android, android-layout

I am newbi so please be patient :)

Why I can't see components on the layout?

I opened an existing project all compiles and looks ok. I opend one of the layouts and I see some components at the component tree, but at the designer I see android...ActionBarOverylayLayout. 
[image]
**how can I see the components ?**
my gradle.build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adafruit.bluefruit.le.connect"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 17
        versionName "2.2.1"
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'     // TODO: remove Apache library and use HttpURLConnection (Apache is deprecated since Android 6.0)

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "zip"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.0.4'
    compile(group: 'org.eclipse.paho', name: 'org.eclipse.paho.android.service', version: '1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.6.1'
}
```

the layout xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/default_background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.adafruit.bluefruit.le.connect.app.UartActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sendLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sendEditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:singleLine="false" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClickSend"
                android:text="@string/uart_send" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sentBytesTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/uart_sentbytes_format"
                android:textColor="@drawable/default_infotextcolor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/receivedBytesTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="@string/uart_receivedbytes_format"
                android:textColor="@drawable/default_infotextcolor" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/sendLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--
          android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          !-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bufferListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#cccccc" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bufferTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClickCopy"
                android:text="@string/uart_copy"
                android:textColor="@drawable/default_textcolor" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClickShare"
                android:text="@string/uart_share"
                android:textColor="@drawable/default_textcolor" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClickClear"
                android:text="@string/uart_clear"
                android:textColor="@drawable/default_textcolor" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: update versions.

Comment: share xml file.

Comment: @Omi added, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml file is working fine you can see the attatched image.

[image]

The problem is you are picking wrong theme check app theme above screen preview section.Change theme from there and select "AppTheme"

Answer (score 0):

you are missing '+' in id resource

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/default_background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.adafruit.bluefruit.le.connect.app.UartActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sendLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sendEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClickSend"
            android:text="@string/uart_send" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sentBytesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/uart_sentbytes_format"
            android:textColor="@drawable/default_infotextcolor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/receivedBytesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="@string/uart_receivedbytes_format"
            android:textColor="@drawable/default_infotextcolor" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sendLayout" //here change
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--
      android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      !-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/bufferListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bufferTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickCopy"
            android:text="@string/uart_copy"
            android:textColor="@drawable/default_textcolor" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickShare"
            android:text="@string/uart_share"
            android:textColor="@drawable/default_textcolor" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickClear"
            android:text="@string/uart_clear"
            android:textColor="@drawable/default_textcolor" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

also update SDK tool and try In menu File -> Invalidate caches/restart